# Update Sql database via editing Textbox C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, textbox

I've got a Winform that update a SQL database by editing the two TextBox Product Name and Product cost, However it doesn't update the database, here is my sample code

```
     private void simpleButton5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string id = comboBox2.Items[comboBox2.SelectedIndex].ToString();
        string name = txtProdName.Text;
        string cost = txtProductCost.Text;
        cn.Open();

        string query = "UPDATE [Product1] SET [Product_Name]= @Product_Name,[Product_Cost]= @Product_Cost where [Product_ID]= @Product_ID";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Product_ID", id);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Product_Name", name);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Product_Price", cost);
        try
        {
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Update Succesfully");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        cn.Close();

    }
```

The datatype of id is `char`, Product_Name is `nvarchar(50)`, Porduct_Cost is `bigint`.
Any thoughts I would appreciated

Comment: do you have any error message receive?

Comment: what's the error msg u r getting and your cost in database is having double or int datatype.

Comment: No Error, it just doesn't work

Comment: put your senstive code inside Try, if u r not getting any error then there must be conversion error because your conversion part is outside the try,put it in inside try block for exect exception plz.

Comment: see my answer hope it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, Convert the string value into int

```
string cost = txtProductCost.Text;
costval=int.Parse(cost)// costval is integer
```

Next, update the database

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Product_Price", costval);
```

Comment: it gives me an Exception "Input string was not in a correct format."

Comment: I think cause it's bigInteger not int

Comment: In fact if you are using AddWithValue, you don't exclipitly convert that to an int value, because it will automatically be converted and inserted as well;)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have a error in conversion, If your cost field in database is bigint then convert

```
string cost = txtProductCost.Text
```

to

```
Int64 cost = Convert.Toint64(txtProductCost.Text);
```

Int64 maps directly to BigInt.

Or if it is Double then convert

```
string cost = txtProductCost.Text
```

to

```
Double cost = Convert.ToDouble(txtProductCost.Text);
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: if u r using Bigint then use Convert.Toint64 instead of Convert.Toint32